# Share Image to Snapchat

Tags: java, android, snapchat

I want to share image to snapchat but giving me "Sorry! You can only share images and videos"
I tried this code but doesnt work [Android share image on snapchat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507693/android-share-image-on-snapchat)

I have this intent

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(number.getText().toString());
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(db.getimage(n))); //This is retrieving the Uri path from DB
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open Snapchat"));
```

Comment: `Uri.fromFile(new File(db.getimage(n))); //This is retrieving the Uri path from DB` Impossible. It should retrieve a file path from db as the File class works with file paths. But then.. we dont know which path that would be. Wrong way of putting a problem here. Further you should not use Uri.fromFile but FileProvider.getUriForFile. And if it is an image the type is probably image/jpeg.

Comment: Possible if I already save the path to DB

Answer (score 0):

the type that you are setting for the setType method is not correct,
if you want to support any format of Image, I suggest you first get the format of Image And after that pass the correct parameter to the setType() method.

for getting a file extension you can use this link:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37951869/how-to-get-the-file-extension-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

For sharing data in snapchat, there is a kit available in their official website called [Creative Kit](https://kit.snapchat.com/docs/creative-kit).

Also you can find the Doc and Tutorials [**here**](https://kit.snapchat.com/docs/creative-kit-android).